NEAT (Neuroevolution): are innovation numbers needed?
This is related to this question: NeuroEvolution: NEAT algorithm innovation numbers
However, I am still struggling to understand why innovation numbers are useful in the first place? As I understand it, there is a one to one mapping between unique genes and innovation numbers and the innovation numbers are used to align genes during cross over.
So why not just align the genes based on the unique keys (input node and output node)? Fine, you lose the ability to distinguish between disjoint and excess genes but maintaining the innovation number dictionary is a bottleneck for parallel processing.
It seems simpler (and faster) to do away with the concept of innovation numbers entirely.
